# Python appending error

Tags: python, append

```
x = []
with open(filechoice) as fileobj:
    for word in fileobj:  
       for ch in word:

           f = ord(ch)
           x = x.append(ord(ch))
```

But it returns this error:

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'"
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Check the documentation for lists: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 3):

The `list.append()` method returns `None`, and you *replaced* the list stored in `x` with that return value:

```
x = x.append(ord(ch))
```

Don't assign back to `x` here; `list.append()` alters the list *in place*:

```
with open(filechoice) as fileobj:
    for word in fileobj:  
       for ch in word:
           x.append(ord(ch))
```

You can use a list comprehension to build the list instead:

```
with open(filechoice) as fileobj:
    x = [ord(ch) for word in fileobj for ch in word]
```

Comment: can't you let someone else answer a python question some times :-|

Comment: Yeah I agree with @DavidGreydanus, you must ignore easy questions. ;)

Comment: @DavidGreydanus: someone [created activity profiles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290419) for the election; I don't answer Python questions [when the circles are small](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JC3/SO2015ActivityProfiles/master/data/combined/plots-daily/activity-35417-Martijn%20Pieters.csv-bubble-nosmoothing.png). *Usually*. :-)